# Parts of HTML are not visible on Chrome PC, but work fine in Chrome OS

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging, invisible

In my website some text is not showing up in Chrome on PC, but it works fine in Chrome on Mac. When I open the inspector, the non-visible html is there in the DOM. Also if I hover over the invisible text the text cursor appears, meaning that it recognizes the text is there. I can also select the invisible text and drag it, and see the "ghost" of the text being dragged around with the no-drop hand symbol that tells me I can not move the text.

I tried to set opacity to 1, to set the color again, and to set visibility to visible, but it doesn't help. I also tried removing the Google font I am using and just using a default font, but this didn't change the problem either. I have tested it on my Macbook Pro Retina and on two windows machines. On all machines Chrome is up to date. I have tested it on Firefox on windows and the problem does not persist. 
Does anyone know whats going on? It is pertaining to my website www.danaavesar.com. The text is dynamically generated using underscore.js template compiler but I dont think that has to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix this bug. I also found out that it wasn't only happening on PC but also on Macs in Chrome. I added transform: translateZ(0) to my elements that were invisible and now they seem to show up!